# JavaScript / jQuery animation: strange for loop behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm javascript newbie...please bear with me.  Modified some jQuery animation code from w3c tutorial.  I'm merely trying to dynamically show the local count (i) variable in the for loop that represents the # of iterations that have taken place for the set of (4) jQuery animation calls.  I was expecting to see the text in the SPAN tag to dynamically change from 0 to 2 after each loop iteration.  However, what actually takes place when button is clicked, is that "count:2" shows up immediately in span tag, then the animation takes place.  This code executes (http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_animation) the same in the following browsers:  Chrome, IE, FireFox, and Safari.  What am i doing wrong and how can I get this to work?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("button").click(function(){
      for(i=0; i<3; i++)
      {
        $("div").animate({height:300},"slow"); //jQuery call 1
        $("div").animate({width:300},"slow");  //jQuery call 2
        $("div").animate({height:100},"slow"); //jQuery call 3
        $("div").animate({width:100},"slow");  //jQuery call 4
        document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="count: "+i;  // JavaScript DOM call
      }
   });
 });

</script> 
</head>

<body>
   <button>Start Animation</button>
   <br /><br />
   <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:relative">
      <span id="count"></span> 
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

__*Original post above...new workking code below this line* __*_*__

```
<html>

 <head>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

  var i=0;

  $("div").animate({height:300},"slow",function(){ document.getElementById      ("count").innerHTML="jQuery Animation 1"; });

  $(document).ready(function(){ $("button").click(function(){ myRecursiveFunction(i); }); });

  function myRecursiveFunction(i)
  {
   document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="count: "+i;

   $("div").animate({height:300},"slow");

   $("div").animate({width:300},"slow");

   $("div").animate({height:100},"slow");

   $("div").animate({width:100},"slow",function(){
    if(i < 10){myRecursiveFunction(++i);}
   });

 }

 </script>

 </head>

 <body>

 <button>Start Animation</button>

 <br /><br />

 <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:relative">

   <span id="count"></span>

 </div>

 </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`animate` is an asynchronous call.

It returns immediately, and the animation happens in the background.

Your entire loop runs instantaneously.

Comment: My apologies for the belated reply,  I was relying on the email mechanism on this board for notifications and did not receive any. Since the animate call is asynchronous then the question becomes:  How does one maintain the state of a counter variable across all these animate calls (4 calls in each for loop iteration)?

Comment: Create a function that takes `i`, performs one iteration, then calls itself with `i + 1` in the callback.

Comment: Not sure how to do this...Can you please provide an example?

Comment: ... Changed code to this:  '
var i=0;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     myRecursiveFunction(i);
  });
});' and included the following recursive function:  'function myRecursiveFunction(i)
{
    $("div").animate({height:300},"slow");
    $("div").animate({width:300},"slow");
    $("div").animate({height:100},"slow");
    $("div").animate({width:100},"slow");
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="count: "+i;
    if(i < 10){myRecursiveFunction(++i);}
}'  ... still shows as count:10

Comment: That's almost correct.  You're calling the function again immediately after the animation starts.  You need to call it in `animate`'s completion callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a callback function that is fired when the animation completes the function would be the fourth argument to the animate call:
http://api.jquery.com/animate/
.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )

```
$("div").animate({width:100},"slow","linear", function (){
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML="count: "+i;
})
```